# Is there a way to make a certain amount of lists based off the length of something

Tags: python

If I have a variable x = [1,2,3,4,5] is there a way to test the length of x and make that many empty lists. So if the length of x is 5 I can make 5 empty lists, or if the length is 6 make 6 empty lists? I want to know if there is an easier way then hard coding the amount of lists like I did in the image.

[This is the test code I have so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4coy.png)

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Don't post images of code, error, data, output, etc. Copy/paste as formatted text here.

Answer (score 2):

```py
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_of_empty_lists = []
for i in range(len(x)):
  list_of_empty_lists.append([])
  # appends that many empty lists of x len

# output : list_of_empty_lists = [[], [], [], [], [] ]
```

Comment: I think we should direct him to some basic articles he should read like these :


https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

https://careerkarma.com/blog/how-to-initialize-a-list-in-python/


They contain a more readable (and probably faster) answer than yours, and it would probably help him more in the long run.

Comment: Alternative solution with a list comprehension: `list_of_empty_lists = [[] for _ in range(len(x))]`

Comment: @Matthias alternative alternative `[[] for _ in x]`.

Comment: @timgeb I knew I overlooked something. Will get a coffee right now.

Comment: @skpn though I agree on what you say try and redirect him to official documentation :)

Comment: @Thomas Webb the algorithm I provided is a very simple one from a coding perspective. Maybe you should get a bit more familiar with list structures and the way you can add elements inside be it an empty list or sth else. Getting to know list comprehensions as mentionned above is quite essential too as they come back often in the programming world of python :)